# maintain common files of two git repositories

Tags: git, github

I have two set of projects with 25 files in which 20 files are common between those two projects except 5 files as it has own logic. I would like to maintain that 20 files as common entity so that if any changes made to those files will get reflected in both the projects. Kindly suggest a best approach.

Comment: A possible solution is to use a common git submodule so you can do version control on those files separately: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-submodule.

Comment: What is the framework?  You really, really don't want to use git as a package management tool.  You should take the 20 common files and build a library, or a module, or whatever object your framework provides for granularity.